Replacement LED lights for ceiling fans
These are all over Aliexpress and Amazon in a variety of physical sizes, wattages, colors, shapes, and other configurations. The light that comes with the original ceiling fan is quite dim. The label says it is 24W, though I don't personally believe that to be the case when I look at it. In this model, the panels are circular, and it looks like something up to abotu 5.75" diameter would physically fit into the glass cover.
I find several different models of LEDs that are 30W-36W at abotu 6.5" dia. But even a slightly smaller diameter never goes above 20W or so. I know that they can only pack so many physical LED components onto a plate of a given size (they still produce some heat), but this cutoff seems arbitrary and irritating.
Is there a rule or formula that would tell me the maximum wattage that they would produce for a given area, so that I could at least rule out the availability of a replacement LED that works for me?

Light intensity is measured in Lumens. So a old 100 watt filament bulb will get very hot and it is identical to 16 watt led. A 20 watt LED is equal to 150 watt filament bulb

Whatever LED system you do get, make sure it is listed as tested by an official government safety organization. Some sources fake these testing markings, and some markings are supposed to mean "self-tested" which really means "not tested". A fire starting with a non-tested or counterfeit-marked device present may not be covered by insurance.

@Traveler I haven't used anything but LED bulbs of one type or another in over a decade. The ceiling fans in question don't even have regular bulb sockets, just a round, flat panel of about 5"dia. I do not know the lumens measurement for those, on the box and in the documentation the ceiling fan has the light described as "24w". Since we're comparing apples to apples (mostly), a higher wattage rating would tend to be brighter.
